# What data structure to use for an observable of an infinite source?

Tags: rx-java2

Whats a clean way to make a Observable/Flowable for a global api like say

```
public void log(String s)
```

All components use this log method that currently has listeners and the various listeners log to various kinds of logging. I want to make it an observable so that multiple subscribers can can subscribe to this observable and log to various files/db.

I am hoping that I won't have to rework the legacy classes (do have access to code of the library).

Currently I add the string to a queue like data structure which is my observable and use subscribers to achieve what I want.
A more generic question would be , how do you create an observable for an infinite source (for me the log method is the source) and what data structure would be recommended for hold the data of this infinite source that can become a good observable.

Any pointers/recommendations/snippets will be greatly appreciated.

**[edit]**
As suggested in the response comment, using PublishSubject solved my problem.
When I need to subscribe I access the subject object and call the subscribe on it.

```
static PublishSubject<LogEvent> subject  = PublishSubject.create();

    public static void log (LogEvent evt) {

        subject.onNext(evt);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you try to achieve and how "infinity" comes into the picture. It sounds like you could simply use `PublishSubject<String>` to dispatch the logged messages.

Comment: for the lifetime of the application various components would call the log method any number of times in that sense I see it as an infinite source. I will look into the documentation of the  PublishSubject class. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd, the `PublishSubject<String> ` solved it for me.